# Download file blob: Proxy Error (The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your Forefront TMG administrator.)

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

0

Hi all,

I am encountering a strange problem. I am downloading file from Azure blob storage using code as below:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = AzureAccountManagement.currentBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);

        BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
        options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, TiMEOUT, 0);

        try
        {
            blob.DownloadToFile(localPath, blob.Name), options);
        }
```

In AzureAccountManagement above, I have configurated correct connection string.

Using code above, when I am downloading a file with .mdb extension, I will get a exception as below:

---

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException was caught

Message=Proxy Error ( The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your Forefront TMG administrator.  )

InnerException:

"The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway."

---

Other trying:

1. When I attempt to download other files(.xml/html/txt), the code successfully download them.
2. I used Azure Storage Explorer to download them, .mdb file --failed with the same error; other file types, successful.
3. I tested on other machines, actually the same configuration as my machine, it successfully download both .mdb file and other file types.

So I think there are some HTTP filter or security problems with my machine, but I don't know how to figure it out. Do you guys have encountered similar issues? If yes, I hope to get solutions from you.

My working machine is Windows 7/64-bit/VS 2010 SP1/Azure SDK 1.6. if the information is useful.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are inside a firewall.

This Error

> The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact your Forefront TMG administrator. )
>
> InnerException:
>
> "The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway."

is actually being served from your firewall - in this case TMG
What this means is the request is being prevented leaving the firewall, and thus is never making it to the blob storage end points.

Have a chat with your network admins and see if they can trace the traffic through the firewall. They might have to flip a switch to allow this traffic through.